# Creating random url in form with get method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a random urls in my script ,

**I want to random this url:**

```
action="https://www.google.com/search?q="
```

**With :**

```
action="https://www.google.com/search?q="
action="https://www.bing.com/search?q="
action="https://search.yahoo.com/search?p="
```

Html :

```
<form id="search-form" target="_blank" method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search?q=">
<input id="aaa" placeholder="..." name="url" type="text">
<input class="bbb" value="search" type="submit">
</form>
```

Thanks ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getRandomUrl() {
  const urls = [
    'https://www.google.com/search?q=',
    'https://www.bing.com/search?q=',
    'https://search.yahoo.com/search?p='
  ]
  return urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]
}

function randomize() {
  const url = getRandomUrl()
  const $form = document.getElementById('search-form')
  $form.setAttribute('action', url)
}

randomize()
```

```html
<form id="search-form" target="_blank" method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
  <input id="aaa" placeholder="..." name="url" type="text">
  <input class="bbb" value="search" type="submit">
</form>

<button onclick="randomize()">random</button>
```